# Write-debug into file and use part of it as variable

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-storage, command-prompt, azure-blob-storage

I need to use `write-debug` to see azure storage access key, but i need to save the output into a txt file, and then find it in that file and use it as variable in powershell, here is my code:

```
$DebugPreference = “Continue”
write-debug (Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName "USWest" -AccountName "mystorageaccountname") | Out-File output.txt
```

Here is a part of output from it:
[image]
Something is wrong as no file is created. Can someone help me to finish the code, I just need to capture key1, that's the long string starting after "value": "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **don't need** to use the [Write-Debug](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113424) cmdlet to get the storage access key.

Here is a simple one-liner which saves the output of `Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey` to `output.txt` using the [Tee-Object](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113417) cmdlet. It then uses [Where-Object](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113423) to filter for `key1` and finally select the `value` property using [Select-Object](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113387) and store it to `$key1Value`:

```
$key1Value = Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName "USWest" -AccountName "mystorageaccountname" | 
    Tee-Object -FilePath output.txt | # save the result to output.txt and keep it in the pipeline
    Where-Object KeyName -eq 'key1' | # filter for the key1
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty value # select the desired value property
```

You can output the value using:

```
$key1Value
```

---

You could also try this:

```
$azureStorageAccountKey = Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName "USWest" -AccountName "mystorageaccountname"
$azureStorageAccountKey | Format-List * -Force | Out-File output.txt
$key1Value = $azureStorageAccountKey | Where-Object KeyName -eq 'key1' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty value
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the problem is that when i don't use Write-Debug, keys are not fully visible, here is the key saved in the txt file after i use your code:

key1                                         F4QkS5E7JrLyb61kcAsmgm8p50vE7tuwHMXISlZSC...                                

As you can see the key are not fully visible, the only way i could get them in full was to do debug.

Comment: does `$key1Value` contain the full value?

Comment: No it doesn't, the output from your code doesn't display the key fully and it's in different format than what i have showed in my screenshot when i did write-debug

Comment: Anyway, calling Write-Debug is the wrong way. You should invoke the `Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey` just as it is, store it in a variable and use something like `Format-List` or `ConvertTo-Json` to format the output for your file. There is also no reason to store the output the same way like you get from Write-Debug...

Comment: Well, i have no idea how to use Format-List or ConvertTo-Json to show the keys fully, any suggestion?

Here is a screenshot of the output file - http://postimg.org/image/jc4w0rpbv/

Comment: First, tell me if one part of your question is answered (if `$key1Value` contains your desired value). Then you have to tell us how the output should look like or you just want to get the full key stored?

Comment: Thank you so much, your second solution works PERFECT!

Comment: You are welcome. Btw. I case you showed us a real access key within your screenshot, I highly recommend you to regenerate your keys...